# Shortest code executed in one thread - C++

Tags: c++, multithreading

What is the shortest piece of code that is executed in one thread in multi-threaded application?

For example, I have a statement `int num = ++last_num;` (`last_num` is a global variable) which is executed asynchronously in several threads and I worry if this is safe, because thread #1 could increment the `last_num` variable, then the same would happen in thread #2 and then the first thread would assign the double-incremented number to `num`. So I'm asking what's the shortest code that is always executed in one thread - is it one command (ending with `;`), one instruction or...?

Thank you

Comment: There is no "shortest code that is always executed in one thread", there are literally thousands of statements you could possibly execute that are perfectly thread safe.

Comment: @Rakete1111 What about my example then? Is that safe or not?

Comment: It's not. You might look into [`std::atomic_int`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic).

Comment: The term you are looking for is "atomic operation". A fundamental operation that cannot be divided. See [`std::atomic`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) for a portable alternative.

Comment: That would be what I'm looking for :) Thank you.

Comment: In a multicore world, code literally executes simultaneously however "small" the instruction. Hardware may impose serial reading/writing of a memory location but cached memory and out-of-order execution scuppers any safety that might have provided. If you want an atomic operation you have to explicitly code for it.